# What is PTS in reference to video encoding?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-encoding, pts

Could someone briefly explain what the acronym PTS means in reference to video encoding?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Presentation Time Stamp.  I couldn't say it any better than the wiki page, found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation_time_stamp

You may also find this relative link here on SO useful: [Can the ffmpeg av libs return an accurate PTS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96107/can-the-ffmpeg-av-libs-return-an-accurate-pts)